# ¿Como puedo redondear un numero decimal a dos cifras después del punto en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Es decir, tengo que imprimir solo un numero entero mas dos cifras después del punto.
Ejemplo: tengo almacenado en la variable `397.4297623`, lo que necesito es imprimir solo `397.43`.

```
    double ajuste = 397.4297623;
    tbxSubsidio.Text = Convert.ToString(ajuste);
```

El resultado de esta impresión obviamente me da el valor de la variable, pero necesito que sea 397.43.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta , agrega el código que has intentado. como dice @Alfabravo tu pregunta puede no ser bien  recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés probar Math.Round:

```
Math.Round(397.4297623, 2)
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, por favor lee [answer] y considera editar para agregar una explicación de modo que la calidad de tu aporte mejore. Saludos

Comment: Recuerda añadir siempre en tus respuestas un breve comentario que explique por qué tu código resuelve la pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

Proba esto. Saludos

```
    float a = 397.4297623F;
    float truncated = (float)(Math.Truncate((double)a*100.0) / 100.0);
    Console.WriteLine(truncated);
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ podes hacerlo en esta consola online

Comment: Recuerda añadir siempre en tus respuestas un breve comentario que explique por qué tu código resuelve la pregunta y cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando necesitas mostrar números al usuario, una buena opción, es usar las [Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#GFormatString), que se usan para dar formato a números.

Acá, no solo vas a tener el beneficio de poder redondear el número, sino que también vas a poder adaptarlo a la cultura necesaria antes de mostrarlo, cosa que por lo general, es muy importante.

Dentro de tu ejemplo en particular, yo usaría el [Especificador de formato numérico ("N")](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#NFormatString).

Para hacerlo, simplemente tenemos que usar la sobrecarga del método [`ToString(String)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_ToString_System_String_) o [`ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) en caso de querer agregarle la cultura específica.

```
//Definimos el número
double numero = 397.4297623;
//Creo dos objetos de culturas diferentes a modo de ejemplo (Argentina)
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culturaArg = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-AR");
//Estados Unidos
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culturaUsa = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
//Muestro el número, con dos decimales y representado cultura Argentina
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("N2",culturaArg)); //Resultado 397,43
//Muestro el número, con dos decimales y representado cultura de Usa
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("N2",culturaUsa)); //Resultado 397.43
```

[*Ejemplo online con dotnetfiddle*](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tt3S3V)